# What color blending algorithm is used to darken a color?

Tags: java, android, colors

I have these cards that have two color shades on them.  A main color, and then a darker accent color:

The main color is given to me in hex, but not the accent.  Can you tell what kind of blend or transformation is being done to the ARGB of the main color to get the darker accent color?

If it matters, I'm developing against Android so I've got access to the Color class and ColorFilter so I can apply all that PorterDuff stuff...

[image]

Comment: Convert to HSL, reduce L, convert back to RGB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want darker `Color`, you can:

1. Convert your RGB to HSV with [`RGBToHSV()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#RGBToHSV%28int,%20int,%20int,%20float%5B%5D%29).
2. Reduce V (lightness value). It's `hsv[2]`, a float with value from 0 to 1.
3. Convert HSV to `Color` with [`HSVToColor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#HSVToColor%28float%5B%5D%29).

If you want darker `Bitmap`,
[`PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html#DARKEN) should work. You just need to calibrate `COLOR` value:

```
private Bitmap getDarkerBitmap(Bitmap src)
{
    final int COLOR = 0xAAFFFFFF;
    final int WIDTH = src.getWidth();
    final int HEIGHT = src.getHeight();
    final Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT, src.getConfig());

    final BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(src);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    drawable.setColorFilter(COLOR, PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
    drawable.draw(new Canvas(result));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I guess I'll just guess and check with the V value until I get a close enough color.  Thank you.

Comment: FYI, this worked great for me.  I just reduced the V value by 50% and it was a spot on color match!  Thanks again, Adam.

Answer (score 3):

Simply do this:

```
int color = ....

int r = Color.red(color);
int b = Color.blue(color);
int g = Color.green(color);

int darkerColor =  Color.rgb((int)(r*.9), (int)(g*.9), (int)(b*.9));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using this code, where if factor < 1, result color will be darker and if factor > 1, result color will be lighter.

```
public static int alterColor(int color, float factor) {
    int a = (color & (0xFF << 24)) >> 24;
    int r = (int) (((color & (0xFF << 16)) >> 16) * factor);
    int g = (int) (((color & (0xFF << 8)) >> 8) * factor);
    int b = (int) ((color & 0xFF) * factor);
    return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I take a look at the provided answers. They are awesome. But here is another way of darkening an int color in Android. As follows:

1. Convert the RGB of your color to HSV using [`RGBToHSV()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#HSVToColor%28float%5B%5D%29) method
2. Reduce V (lightness value) using a float factor. It's in `hsv[2]` and a float number ranges from 0 to 1.
3. Convert HSV to Color using [`HSVToColor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#HSVToColor%28float%5B%5D%29) method and then return

This is the snippet:

```
public static int getDarkerColor(int color, float factor) {
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.RGBToHSV(Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color), hsv);
    hsv[2] = hsv[2] * factor;
    return  Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
}
```

Note that when you give the `factor` 0.9f, you want to darken the input color at the rate of 10% ((1-0.9) * 100).

Answer (score 0):

To darken a color, you just need to remove the same amount from the red green and blue components.

Edit: Since you're getting the color from an hexadecimal value, you need to separate the components from it, decrease its value and put it back in.

0xaarrggbb ->
a = alpha
r = red
g = green
b = blue

```
int color = 0xff445566;

// Get the color component:
int alpha |= a << 24;
int red |= r << 16;
int green |= g << 8;
int blue |= b;

int newalpha = alpha;
int newred = red - proportional amount ;
int newgreen = green - proportional amount ;
int newblue = blue - proportional amount ;


// Set the color component
color = (color & ~(0xFF << 24)) | (newalpha << 24);
color = (color & ~(0xFF << 16)) | (newred << 16);
color = (color & ~(0xFF << 8)) | (newgreen << 8);
color = (color & ~0xFF) | newblue;
```

Comment: To be more accurate, you want to remove a *proportional* amount of each r,g,b. If your original color is `20,80,200`, taking 10 from each would not simply darken. It would change the hue also. HSV/HSL is a better color space in general for something like this, though.

Comment: True for the proportional amount - modified so at least the answer is valid. =)

Answer (score 0):

`java.awt.Color.darker()` multiplies every 0-255 component (R, G, B) with 0.7 and then casts it back to `int`.

Comment: True, but `android.graphics.Color` doesn't have similar method.